# Keypress to jump to item in DropDownList based on custom search

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I allow a user to open a dropdownlist, and then type a few letters to jump to the correct item?  I'll need to implement my own search logic because the formatting is fixed, and not searchable as-is (all begin with an open parentheses), but I'm not sure how to hook the behavior.  Jquery is preferred, but anything that will work cross-browser will do.

Example:

(AABE) Able Air Conditioning

(BAE) Bark Air Equipment

Typing 'ba' should jump to the second entry, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that you can listen to the KeyPress event and change selectedIndex to the found item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, you can use the keydown event. The following code can be viewed live here: http://jsfiddle.net/TXZWC/26/

HTML:

```
<select name="companies">
    <option value="">choose</option>
    <option value="1" data-search-match="AABE">(AABE) Able Air Conditioning</option>
    <option value="2" data-search-match="BAE">(BAE) Bark Air Equipment</option>
</select>

<a id="clear-search" href="#">Clear Search</a>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   var $select = $('select'),
        searchQuery = '';

    $(document).on('keydown', function (e){

        // get the char value and append to search string
        searchQuery += String.fromCharCode(e.which);

        // unselect previously selected option
        deselectSelectedOption();

        // find matching option                
        var $selected = $select.find('option').filter(function(){            
            return $(this).data('search-match') === searchQuery;
        });

        if($selected){
            $selected.attr('selected', 'true');
        }                      
    });    

     $('#clear-search').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       searchQuery = '';                        
       deselectSelectedOption();
       $select.find('option').first().attr('selected', 'true');
    });

    function deselectSelectedOption(){
        $select.find('option[selected]').removeAttr('selected');     
    }        
});​
```

Comment: Thanks, though the JSFiddle example isn't working for me in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work either.  Tried IE and Chrome.

Comment: Are you clicking in the box first so it has  focus? Click underneath the dropdown in that pane first then type aabe

Comment: ah ok, I see.  Thanks, that's closer, but the hope was that even a first character match would jump to the first entry.  This requires a complete search before a match is found.  Additionally, I won't be able to add the data-search markup to the select itself, it's an asp.net dropdownlist.

Comment: Incorrect. You can add attributes using .Attributes.Add("data-search-value") etc. A partial match is as simple as indexOf(str) == 0. I'm not going to spend any more time updating this. I thought you had some basic knowledge of JS and ASP.NET.

Comment: Did you downvote me after I spent 25 mins on this crap? I downvoted you too now.

Comment: I will take away your downvote as soon as you take away mine. I understand I may have come off a little harsh but that doesn't justify marking me down after I spent most of my lunch break giving you a way to accomplish what you needed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16795/discussion-between-grant-h-and-gho5t)